# CRLfile: none??? Trying to update R to latest version been googling for days

Tags: r

Ubuntu 14.04
I get an error after

```
sudo apt-get update
###other stuff###
Err https://cran.mtu.edu trusty/ Packages           
server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none

gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys E084DAB9
gpg: requesting key E084DAB9 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" not changed

gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | sudo apt-key add -
OK

sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 152 not upgraded.
```

But....

```
~$ R

 R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) -- "Frisbee Sailing"
 Copyright (C) 2013 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

These seem to be the instructions on https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README and various blog posts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I use for up to date R and CRAN packages is adding Michael Rutter's PPAs (also used by CI-Travis):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/c2d4u
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: This is what I got back                                                                                                                'Fetched 5,132 kB in 7s (720 kB/s)
W: Failed to fetch https://cran.mtu.edu/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu/trusty/Packages  server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none'

Comment: This is from the repository you added first, that wasn't correctly identified. After you add the PPAs as I described, you can remove those from the Software Sources program.

Comment: I just entered the code you put down. Was I supposed to do something else? Brand new. Oh I should remove that from the sources.list?

Comment: Yes, it adds two [PPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive), updates the package database, and upgrades installed packages. Since you already have `R` installed, and (presumably) some CRAN pacakges as well, those will all be updated.

Comment: If the answer solved your question then, please accept the answer by clicking on [the upvote arrow and then the tick below it](http://i.imgur.com/YN8AQkd.png?1).